# Jquery Blur Event when a New tab is opened

Tags: jquery, onblur

I am using a textarea and onblur of it some action is performed. But When I open a new tab / change Tab, the blur event is getting triggered. How do I avoid it, How Can I differentiate the event blur and Tab change?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you **not** want it to perform a `blur` event when you're obviously focusing away from the text field?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to perform on blur when I am out of the tab working on (say Tab1), because once I am back to the Tab1, I don't want things getting changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `change` handler? This will only trigger if you're content has changed in some manner.

Comment: Hi, I cant use change handler for textarea, Can I? For every letter I type it gets triggered then.

Comment: I was under the impression the change is fired when you either focus on another element or click the submit button. As the jQuery documentation describes: 'The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.'